# Route to address using intent

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

To route to an address using intent I am to use

```
Intent directionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
  Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=realAddress"));
  startActivity(directionIntent);
```

In which I can type the real human readable address. But I am not sure how to include the address. Say the address is `123 Mn Guy, Mountain View, CA 12345` and I have it as a string. how do I attach it to the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it in the query string. Like this:

```
String address = "123 Mn Guy, Mountain View, CA 12345";
Uri navigationUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + address);
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, navigationUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks. Will let you know after testing complete. Thanks.